Как правильно интерпретировать ответ в аудите и оценить его корректность?
СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте. Не волнуйтесь => Я не волнуюсь, а не понимаю ответ
Сегодня первый раз мне попалась "проверка" в "проверке" (настоящая(?))
Выглядит она так

Я пометила тревогой, мне показался и ответ "общим" и отвечающий "странным", потом же мне открылось

Но ответа я не поняла. Хоть и читала и запоминала.
Мне бы хотелось от профессионалов получить ответ на ответ и его значение. Возможно под другим ракурсом, для общего развития и понимания.
Вот вопрос с ответом

Видел этот ответ ещё в оригинальном вопросе в момент его публикации и тоже сразу всё понял. Возможно, вы просто бесконечно далеки от C++

@andremal, именно поэтому и задала вопрос для общего развития. Я подумала, если у кого будет время и желание, то "разжует"

Мне же надо как то запомнить, там же написано запоминайте/понимайте

Ну в контексте проверок это наверно стоит интерпретировать как — не слишком буянить в вопросах и ответах по темам, в которых не хватает компетенций

@andremal, оу оу оу, полегче, если "буянить" это про меня. Я за 6 лет в общем и целом тревог 80 поставила и тщательно обдумываю прежде чем флагнуть. Если тема не знакома смотрю на ответ, этот ответ содержит такие фразы, а зачем вам скорость, а не нужно, это только профессионала доступно... По мне не оч отвечает, или я должна понять не понимаемое. Взять на заметку комментарии адекватные. И получить новые знания.

почему ответ показался "общим" и отвечающий "странным"?

@Grundy, компилятор предполагает, ваш вопрос не содержателен, требуется большой опыт, чтоб определить... (эти фразы общего характера) а на счёт странный, я впервые увидела "безликого" поэтому насторожилась, подумала вирус какой...

Но я прочитала ответ Qwertiy, возможно мне надо время переварить, чтоб понять

Я вопрос задала не для обсуждения, что его ответ хорош или плох, а чтоб для себя понять значение сложного написания. По-моему это разрешено здесь. Почему мы перешли в русло, что его ответ прекрасен для тех, кому си плюс знаком. Сайт даёт ступеньку, знания повышений, я пытаюсь следовать. Есть ситуация- возник вопрос-ожидается понимание

эти фразы общего характера - Они расположены в пояснении и, в основном, не относятся к вопросу. Про предположения компилятора - не является фразой общего характера, к тому же, далее в ответе следуют пояснения.

Ответ вполне адекватен вопросу, там автор спрашивает что-то про сферических коней в вакууме, отвечающий ему объясняет, что вопрос бесполезен. Вы не сможете понять его в деталях, не вникая в кухню С++: бесконечные дебаты про "что стандарт говорит по этому поводу" и т.п. Тревогать такие расплывчатые ответы не надо, если конечно там не ChatGPT.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight, я начала изучать тему, и это очень полезно, думаю на выходных отпишусь. Если есть возможность подниматься по ступеням, то я стараюсь ее использовать. Были указаны термины, ответ Qwertiy тоже открыл окошко. У меня уже почти готов мой ответ и описание ситуации(тут было затронуто несколько аспектов и думаю, я прощупала их со всех сторон для себя).

@MSDN.WhiteKnight кстати, если отойти от темы, но по вашему комментарию вопрос:=> если явно видно ChatGPT, то ведь такой причины нету вроде для "флага" (?) // только комментарий можно написать, почему запрещены ответы от такового, и ссылку приложить (?)

Да, нестандартный флаг с комментарием, либо "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством", если она появляется.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight, А, ок, буду знатьотлично. Я думала нет флага, и писала комментарии с ссылкой на.... Зачем плохо ии

Правильно что пометили, но не правильно, что общим или т.п. Там просто серьезная ошибка в обсуждаемой функции, поэтому обсуждене (ответы) всех участников не имеют смысла. (Что же касается сути вашего вопроса на мете, то я бы посоветовал вообще не притрагиваться к темам в которых вы не специализируетесь)

@avp, аудит был полгода назад, в чате вспомнила, что был вопрос такой, стала искать, а заголовок мне показался "не говорящим", я вчера не есть я сегодня... Изменила заголовок... А так если честно интересно узнавать новое, поэтому я даже при проверках (если не знаю темы) сижу и прям изучаю... Открываю статьи информацию ищу... Но порой также бывает, что "пропускаю" проверку.

@Dev18, изучать -- это хорошо, а вот оценивать, если чего-то не знаете -- не стоит.

@avp, неужели вы не согласны, что  у ответа есть определённая норма?помимо там ключевых моментов есть же ещё и "пример" ответа. Почему нельзя изучить, а потом оценить. Я иногда могу и час потратить на проверке. Там же не дессертация, а ответ. Да и вообще я сейчас придерживаюсь того, что если ответ хотя-бы на 10 процентов ответ, то это уже проходит проверку. Поэтому оцениваю только то, что совсем не ответ...

@Dev18, вы зубы лечить к человеку, который только изучает это дело пойдете? Вот и тут должно быть устроено так же. К сожалению, оценивают (в т.ч. закрывая, т.е. совершая практически необратимое действие) тут все кому не лень

@avp, тогда пожалуйста иногда хотя бы в проверки заходите. Там очередь висит. Вы же по си плюсам. Будете тем самым хорошим дантистом. Все сюда по си плюсам из за вас будут заходить.

По умолчанию в очередях проверок сообщения никак не фильтруются. Каждый участник, получивший доступ к очередям, видит одно и то же. Чтобы сделать очереди немного кастомизированными для них есть фильтры, например, в очереди на закрытие такие:



Если в фильтре выбрать метки по своим технологиям, то вероятность непонимания качественного ответа или вопроса должна заметно уменьшиться. Нельзя быть экспертом во всём.
Возможно, что для аудита в очередях эти фильтры работать не будут или будут работать как-то иначе, например, можно получить в аудите что-то с другими метками, не попадающими под фильтр. Это можно попробовать уточнить на MSE.
Объяснять с подробностями ответ с основного сайта на Мете мне не кажется правильным. Лучше задать вопрос сразу на основном сайте и сослаться на имеющийся (непонятный) ответ.

если не разберусь сама(тк, после вчера уже начала копать и достаточно удачно, вчера когда задавала все казалось иначе, сейчас же сама нашла что и где искать, да и тут были фразы, которые помогли), то задам, => но мне почему то казалось это возможным задать здесь для обсуждения...

мне не кажется правильным. => а есть запреты ? или может какая ссылка, по рекомендациям ?

@Dev18 Мета - для обсуждений сайта. А если какие-то вопросы по технологиям, покрываемым основным сайтом, то там и следует их задавать. Здесь мы могли бы обсудить, например, "почему сообщение попало в аудит, если казалось бы, не должно туда попадать" и т.п. Но уж точно не неопределённое поведение в C++ и его друзей.

Я прочитал ответ на скриншоте и полностью понимаю его.
Также из него я понимаю, что в вопросе речь идёт о си или си++ и подобной функции: int f(int x) { if (x == 1) return x; }. И эта функция каким-то образом участвует в замере времени выполнения, что несколько странно для вопросов по UB, которое обычно предполагает, что код вообще не работает задуманным способом.
В общем, я абсолютно согласен, что ответ хороший. А судя по галочке, автора вопроса он тоже устроил.


Stanislav Volodarskiy очень симпатичен/компетентен/и только хороший отзыв и ответы под его ником, хочется читать, чтоб узнавать, что то новое

по вопросу:

можно понять, что значит ответ "под другим ракурсом" спросить, чтоб получить ответ, но мало кто захочет расписывать/разжевывать, поэтому спрашивать на мете о таком, как сказано в комментариях малоуместно

1.2 Но все же были комментарии/ответы, которые дали понять общий смысл и по другому прочитать ответ. На этот раз я прочитала более внимательно код в вопросе, увидев присвоение переменной (В первой функции ReturnIntX(int x) возвращается сам аргумент x, если он равен 1. Во второй функции ReturnInt1(int x) возвращается литерал 1, если x равен 1 - это почти тоже самое  в целом, то есть вопрос сам по себе отвечает) поначалу я прочла только вопрос о поиске что то типа бенчмарка для производительности...
1.3 поэтому совет - читайте вопрос еще более внимательней, чтоб оценить ответ
рекомендации ТС:

Можно поставить фильтр, как сказанно в комментариях, чтоб просматривать/проверять только то, что "знаешь", но у меня профиль широкий, и мне нравится узнавать также и новое, поэтому этот вариант я не рассматриваю, но он имеет место быть

2.1 Можно "пропустить", если есть доля сомнений, но тогда есть риск, что "странный" останется в ленте. Почему "странный", потому что отвечающий был замаскирован, как и сказано в вопросе, и безликий участник настораживает, словно вирус какой. Такая ошибка впринципе бывает только раз, потому что, если увидеть раз аудит, то можно понять/запомнить, что а, ок такое поведение бывает, что участник "скрыт" итд
резюме и рекомендации, общая картина:

Мне бы все таки хотелось отписаться об ответе и оставить рекомендации для себя самой и тех, кто прочтет. Если отвечать "бруско" с фразами немного резковатыми, показывая ответ "на пальцах"('Требуется большой опыт чтобы определить надежно "скорость функции"'), можно все таки и ответить к примеру на вопрос. То есть, написать про компилятор итд, фразы, которые могут быть непонятны ("Компилятор предполагает, что программист не допускает") тем, кто не в теме, а в конце например оставить ресурсы на "тестовик", ведь конечное предложение с единственным вопросом указывает

"P.s.: Могли бы подсказать библиотеки для самостоятельной проверки?"
то есть ответа на вопрос как такового нету. Рассмотрен "конкретный пример" Ответ пытается донести, что современные компиляторы очень агрессивно оптимизируют код, и что в данном примере обе функции могут быть оптимизированы до одинакового простого результата. Поэтому, сравнивать их производительность не имеет смысла, потому что результат будет одинаковым. Это я поняла спустя время, и спасибо за полезность данного аудита, мне открылись новые знания.
плохие стороны ответа:
a) Важно подчеркнуть, что это действительно является UB (undefined behavior) в C++ (я узнала это из ответа Qwertiy и это дало ключ к тому, что искать, пересмотреть вопрос ТС итд)
b) Описание оптимизаций, которые может сделать компилятор, слишком сложное и может запутать.
c) Не дается четкого ответа на вопрос, какая из двух функций быстрее, и почему. Вместо этого сосредоточено внимание на теоретических аспектах оптимизации.
d) Не предложены ресурсы или инструменты для проверки и понимания(Google Benchmark, gprof, или valgrind)
хорошие стороны ответа:
a) Детально объясняется, как компилятор может оптимизировать вызов функции, если он определяет, что результат вызова всегда будет одинаковым
b) Четко указано, что отсутствие возвращаемого значения из функции, ожидающей возвращаемое значение, является UB в C++
c) Правильно упомянуто, что измерение скорости выполнения отдельных функций может быть неточным и что производительность программы в целом более показательна

плохие стороны ответа: Важно подчеркнуть, что является UB ... хорошие стороны ответа: Четко указано, что является UB.

@wololo, Спасибо за ваш отзыв. Можно ситуацию с ремонтом стены ? Перед тем, как начать работу, важно знать, что "она" должна быть подходящей для поверхности стены. Если вы наносите её неправильно, то высохнет она так быстро, как предсказано и не получится желаемый результат. вы поняли о чем речь ? Незная "КРАСКА",  врятли. так же и в моем описании, я пишу, что => Важно подчеркнуть, что это UB - то есть написать "UB" , вспомните Алису, Грибаааа))) https://www.youtube.com/shorts/mPstyltx4hs
